# Kusto get resourcegroups and subscription information

Tags: azure, kql, azure-resource-graph

How can I get resource group name, subscription name and id for all the resource groups?

I can get all resourcegroups with

```
Resources| distinct resourceGroup
```

But if I add "id" in there I get same resourcegroup multiple times.

```
Resources | distinct resourceGroup, id
```

Comment: What do you mean *if I add "id" in there*? Can you post the query with the id?

Comment: I understand, you want to pull the subscription Name, resource group name, id using the resource graph explorer. you can use the below KQL query.
**
resourcecontainers
| where type == "microsoft.resources/subscriptions"
| join ( resourcecontainers | where type == "microsoft.resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups") on subscriptionId
| distinct name,name1,id1
| project SubscriptionName=name,resourceGroupName=name1, resourceGroupId=id1

Comment: that is exactly what I need. could you submit it as an answer?

Comment: @Kamsiinov I have posted the above comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand, you want to pull the subscription Name, resource group name, id using the resource graph explorer. you can use the below KQL query.

```html
resourcecontainers 
| where type == "microsoft.resources/subscriptions" 
| join ( resourcecontainers | where type == "microsoft.resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups") on subscriptionId 
| distinct name,name1,id1 
| project SubscriptionName=name,resourceGroupName=name1, resourceGroupId=id1
```